# How to force class ignore style settings

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using `Jquery Mobile`. When I create an input text for example `select box`, it 
wraps it with some `HTML`. one of the rows is:

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-d ui-icon-shadow"></span>
```

In our project we have a lot of overriding on those classes, especially `ui-icon`:

```
.ui-icon {
        background-size: 85px 700px !important;
}
```

so I get a page with those parameters, all my page get messy because of that.

Changing the style in all projects is a lot of work, how can I force my page to ignore this style (`background-size`) for that current class is `ui-icon` ?

Comment: [Don't use `!important`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3706819/139010)

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced it's a dupe, though I think it overlaps with your own question, but have you looked at: [jQuery mobile - dynamically changing CSS with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731238/jquery-mobile-dynamically-changing-css-with-javascript)?

Comment: do you want to turn off JQM styles on input?

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/7VvFy/

Comment: @Omar It something similar to what I was searching, but I interesting in disabling a specific value, for example background-size.

Comment: Could you please make a jsfiddle to show us what you exactly need.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot force a class to ignore styles (from what I know anyway).

I think the only option you have (with jQuery) is to over-ride the `background-size`

```
$('.ui-icon').css('cssText', 'background-size: auto auto !important');
```

Mind you I would never recommend coding like this, you are doing a lot wrong if you have to use `!important` in both **CSS** & **JAVASCRIPT**

Comment: jQuery doesn't understand `!important` that's why we are applying it directly with cssText.

Comment: There's really no point in using `!important` in an inline style attribute.

Comment: @MattBall and why is that? `!important` rules over-ride inline styles.

Comment: I use `!important` in my user styles - using Stylish in browser. It is pretty useful in here, but I guess it would be way less effective if it was used in the original CSS, too.

Answer (score 1):

CSS styling takes the last style committed to it and then can only be overridden with Important, your question is very vague but you should be able to resolve this by hard coding the style on the element,

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-d ui-icon-shadow" style="background-size: 5px 5px !important;"></span>
```

Or to override the entire class with the !Important element. for this you have to create the style lastly called in your list of styles for that page only, so for instance creating the class on said page.

Other than that you could use Javascript to set the styling for that element specific by giving the Element an id,

```
 $('#txtBoxOverride').css('background', '5px 5px !important')
```